# Chaining in EventEmitters in JavaScript and calling emitter.emit() before emitter.on()

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-handling

In an example the **event.on()** was called after **event.emit()** method but still the results appeared. I know that some wehre it is related to chaining but can anyone explain the chaining and the cause why the order of operations isn't a concern in the example

```
 var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
   var fs = require('fs');


function findPattern(files, regex) {
     var emitter = new EventEmitter();
     files.forEach(function(file) {
       fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(err, content) {
         if(err)
           return emitter.emit('error', err);
         emitter.emit('fileread', file);
         var match = null;
         if(match = content.match(regex))
           match.forEach(function(elem) {
             emitter.emit('found', file, elem);
         });         });
   });
     return emitter;
   }


   findPattern(
       ['fileA.txt', 'fileB.json'],
       /hello \w+/g
     )
     .on('fileread', function(file) {
       console.log(file + ' was read');
     })
     .on('found', function(file, match) {
       console.log('Matched "' + match + '" in file ' + file);
     })
     .on('error', function(err) {
       console.log('Error emitted: ' + err.message);
     });
```

Comment: The order of operations isn't a concern because the order of operations is correct, 1) create emitter 2) make async fs calls 3) listen for events 4) fs callbacks emit events.   event.on is being called before event.emit

Comment: @generalhenry thanks :) I got your point but what if instead of fs function some sync function was there. In that case would the flow have been same ? because the .emit function would have executed before the .on function in that case

Comment: `const e = new events.EventEmitter(); e.emit('test'); e.on('test', console.log.bind(console, 'test fired'));`  does not fire test